# My while loop for determining an appropriate font size is going too far... sometimes?

Tags: java, while-loop, fonts, jframe, fontmetrics

I'm doing a project for school that requires me to read a file and make a bar graph with the data read. I have made a class that makes a JFrame and paints rectangles to divide the frame into a section for the name of each data (football player name) and one for the bars (age of player).  I have a method that is meant to increase a font size until the longest (printed) string takes up the width that is allotted space, and return a font of that size to be used in the paint method.

It works when the initial JFrame is created, but as I resize it, it sometimes increases the font size 1 to large, but not always. I am at a loss. The console output shows (to me) that the condition of my while loop was not met, but the font size was still increased... any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
private Font myFont(int allowedW, int allowedH, int numData) {
    // needs to check length of font and size of JFrame and set font (size)
    // accordingly
    String longest = "";
    int fontSize = 1;
    Font f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
    for (BarData b : this.graphData) {
        if (getFontMetrics(f).stringWidth(b.getName()) > getFontMetrics(f)
                .stringWidth(longest)) {
            longest = b.getName();
        }
    }
    while ((getFontMetrics(f).stringWidth(longest) < allowedW)){
            //&& ((getFontMetrics(f).getHeight() * numData) < allowedH)) {
            f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
        System.out.println(longest);
        System.out.println("length " + getFontMetrics(f).stringWidth(longest));
        System.out.println("allowed width " + allowedW);
        System.out.println(fontSize);
        fontSize++;
    }
    return f;
}
```

output looks something like this when i drag to resize the jframe:

Demaryius Thomas
length 150
allowed width 158
17
Demaryius Thomas
length 170
allowed width 158
18

Comment: The `f` returned is not the largest font size that's less than `allowedW`, but actually the next one, which may be 1 too large.

Comment: Your code always returns a font that is one size larger than allowed. After the while loop, create a Font object with size `fontSize-1` and return that.

Comment: I have tried adding f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize - 1); after the while loop but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - `new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize)` use the constant for compile time checking. I.E. `new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, fontSize)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while loop like this,

```
while ((getFontMetrics(f).stringWidth(longest) < allowedW)){
            //&& ((getFontMetrics(f).getHeight() * numData) < allowedH)) {
        System.out.println(longest);
        System.out.println("length " + getFontMetrics(f).stringWidth(longest));
        System.out.println("allowed width " + allowedW);
        System.out.println(fontSize);
        fontSize++;
        f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize);//your f is not updated after increasing fontSize, if you put it as first statement.
    }
return new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize - 1);
```

Comment: That's a nicer way to write the loop but it still returns a font that is one size too large.

Comment: yes, but then your return statement should be like this, return new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize - 1); In your earlier code it will not work, but now it should.